# I want to set a caption or description position in galleryitem control of devexpress

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, devexpress

[My Image Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dAJ9.png)

I'm create a GalleryItem and attached a image to GalleryControl.

by the way, description position is always right of image.

I want to change the position to bottom of image.

How can I move it?

```
List<GalleryItem> galleryItemList = new List<GalleryItem>();
GalleryItem gi = new GalleryItem();
BitmapImage bmpImg = new BitmapImage();
bmpImg.BeginInit();
bmpImg.UriSource = newUri(@"C:\temp\2.jpg");
bmpImg.EndInit();
gi.Glyph = bmpImg;
gi.Description = Path.GetFileName(bmpImg.UriSource.LocalPath);
galleryItemList.Add(gi);
myGalleryItemGroup.ItemSource = galleryItemList;
```

It is my code.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your code?

Comment: You're using a custom library that provides WPF controls with default templates. You likely need to supply a custom template for GalleryItem to change its position.

Comment: I never used GalleryItem myself, but you can try to set `Gallery.ItemGlyphLocation` to `Top`. [DevExpress docs link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.Gallery.ItemGlyphLocation.property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [`Gallery.ItemGlyphLocation`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.Gallery.ItemGlyphLocation.property) to `Top`.

```
xmlns:dxb="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/bars"

<dxb:GalleryControl>
    <dxb:Gallery ItemGlyphLocation="Top">
        <dxb:GalleryItemGroup x:Name="myGalleryItemGroup">
            <!--...-->
        </dxb:GalleryItemGroup>
    </dxb:Gallery>
</dxb:GalleryControl>
```

Also, it might be best to direct your questions to DevExpress the next time you have one. Their customer support is awesome.